# SilverStripe login form customisation

Tags: php, silverstripe

What's the easiest way to customise the default silverstripe login form? My final goal is to apply `->setExtraClass('myClass')` to the login action button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3.4 we can extend `MemberLoginForm`, set the action in our constructor and then set SilverStripe to use the custom log in class as the default log in class.

First we create a `CustomMemberLoginForm` class:

**mysite/code/CustomMemberLoginForm.php**

```
class CustomMemberLoginForm extends MemberLoginForm {

    public function __construct($controller, $name, $fields = null, $actions = null, $checkCurrentUser = true) {

        $actions = FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('dologin', _t('Member.BUTTONLOGIN', 'Log in'))->addExtraClass('myClass'),
            LiteralField::create(
                'forgotPassword',
                '<p id="ForgotPassword"><a href="Security/lostpassword">'
                . _t('Member.BUTTONLOSTPASSWORD', "I've lost my password") . '</a></p>'
            )
        );

        parent::__construct($controller, $name, $fields, $actions);
    }
}
```

In our `mysite/_config.php` we add the following code to tell SilverStripe to use our custom log in class:

**mysite/_config.php**

```
Object::useCustomClass('MemberLoginForm', 'CustomMemberLoginForm');
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to override the default `FormAction.ss` template file and add the class in there:

*themes/[theme-name]/templates/forms/FormAction.ss*

```
<% if $UseButtonTag %>
    <button class="action btn medium solid" $AttributesHTML>
        <% if $ButtonContent %>$ButtonContent<% else %>$Title.XML<% end_if %>
    </button>
<% else %>
    <input class="action extra class here" $AttributesHTML />
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: The only problem is `$AttributesHTML` will add an extra `class` attribute, which results in invalid and incorrect html mark up. On the log in form the resulting html is `<input class="action extra class here" type="submit" name="action_dologin" value="Log in" class="action" id="MemberLoginForm_LoginForm_action_dologin" />`. It's a shame because I think this is the nicer solution if you want to add these classes to every form action.

Comment: I know this answer is pretty old now but you can exclude duplicate attributes using `$getAttributesHTML("class")` (to exclude the `class` attribute but insert everything else).